# Fast mysql random weighted choice on big database

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I build a website where i need to choose random-weighted record
from database.

There is a snipped of code in [SQL : select one row randomly, but taking into account a weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398113/sql-select-one-row-randomly-but-taking-into-account-a-weight/14612282#14612282)

```
SELECT t.*, RAND() * t.weight AS w 
FROM table t 
ORDER BY w DESC
LIMIT 1
```

It works fine on small sample of records.

When trying on close to 1 mln records it  gets slow ( 1.3 - 1.8 second)
on my local machine, and i guess that i would take even longer on even bigger sets.

How could it be optimised?
Are there better ways to randomly choose weighted record?

<strike>My attempt at it would be to calculate the weights on regular basis, store them in separate table, choose random number programmaticaly and search for closest record to this number.</strike>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: Select Random Entry, but Weight Towards Certain Entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417621/mysql-select-random-entry-but-weight-towards-certain-entries)

Answer (score 2):

You could partition the data based on weight, then randomly select a partition.

Determine the partition to use: O(n)

```
SELECT Weight, FLOOR(RAND()*COUNT(*)) as Target 
FROM test 
GROUP BY Weight
ORDER BY RAND()*(Weight)*count(Weight)/100 DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Use Weight and Target from previous query to get result: O( Log(n) )

```
SELECT test.*
FROM test
WHERE Weight = $Weight
LIMIT $Target, 1
```

Test it:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `Id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Weight` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `Weight` (`Weight`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


insert into test (Weight) ( select FLOOR(RAND()*1000) );
```

run 20 times to create 1 million test rows:

```
insert into test (Weight) select FLOOR(rand()*1000) as Weight from test;
```

The first query runs in O(n) because of the GROUP BY. You can get it down to log(n) running time if you maintain a second table that keeps track of the count for each weight.

On my database with 8 million rows in the test table the first query runs in `(6.089 s)` and the second in `(0.001 s)`

Answer (score 0):

First get the sum of all weights so that you can calculate the probability of each row being selected on the fly.

```
SELECT SUM(weight) FROM t;
```

I'll assume the sum amount is accessible through a mysql variable named @TOTAL_WEIGHT

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM t
WHERE RAND() <= (weight / @TOTAL_WEIGHT)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

There's a chance that this goes through the whole table and still doesn't find a match, in which case you'd probably just run another query to get one random row.