# Advertisement System Tips

Tags: php, sql, laravel, probability, ads

I am creating an advertisement system which shows the highest bidder's ads more frequently.

Here is an example of the table structure I am using, but simplified...

```
+----+----------+------------------------+----------------------+-----+
| id | name     | image                  | destination          | bid |
+----+----------+------------------------+----------------------+-----+
| 1  | abc, co  | htt.../blah            | htt...djkd.com/      | 3   |
+----+----------+------------------------+----------------------+-----+
| 2  | facebook | htt.../blah            | htt...djkd.com/      | 200 |
+----+----------+------------------------+----------------------+-----+
| 3  | google   | htt.../blah            | htt...djkd.com/      | 78  |
+----+----------+------------------------+----------------------+-----+
```

Now, right now I am selecting the values from the database and then inserting them into an array and picking one out by random similar to the following:

```
$ads_array = [];
$ads = Ad::where("active", "=", 1)->orderBy("price", "DESC");

if ($ads->count() > 0) {
    $current = 0;
    foreach ($ads->get() as $ad) {
        for ($i = 0; $i <= ($ad->price == 0 ? 1 : $ad->price); $i++) {
            $ads_array[$current] = $ad->id;
            $current++;
        }
    }

    $random = rand(0,$current-1);
    $ad = Ad::where("id", "=", $ads_array[$random])->first();

    ...
}
```

So, essentially what this is doing is, it is inserting the advert's ID into an array `1*$bid` times. This is very inefficient, sadly (for obvious reasons), but it was the best way I could think of doing this.

Is there a better way of picking out a random ad from my database; while still giving the higher bidders a higher probability of being shown?

Comment: might be a good read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398113/sql-select-one-row-randomly-but-taking-into-account-a-weight

Comment: @b.enoit.be Says not to use the answer... thanks though. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this might do the trick (but all the credit go to this [guy in the comments](http://www.kahunaburger.com/2008/10/13/selecting-random-weighted-records-from-mysql/#comment-42836))

```
SELECT ads.*
FROM ads
ORDER BY -log(1.0 - rand()) / ads.bid
LIMIT 1
```

A script to test this :

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;', 'test', 'test');


$times = array();

// repeat a lot to have real values
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT ads.* FROM ads ORDER BY -log(1.0 - rand()) / bid LIMIT 1');
    $bid = $stmt->fetch()['bid'];
    if (isset($times[$bid])) {
        $times[$bid] += 1;
    } else {
        $times[$bid] = 1;
    }
}

// echoes the number of times one bid is represented
var_dump($times);
```

The figures that comes to me out of that test are pretty good :

```
// key is the bid, value is the number of times this bid is represented
array (size=3)
  200 => int 7106
  78 => int 2772
  3 => int 122
```

Further reference on mathematical explanation

> Many important univariate distributions can be sampled by inversion using simple closed form expressions. Some of the most useful ones are listed here.
>
> Example 4.1 (Exponential distribution). The standard exponential distribution has density f(x) = e−x on x > 0. If X has this distribution, then E(X) = 1, and we write X ∼ Exp(1). The cumulative distribution function is F(x) = P(X  x) = 1 − e−x, with F−1(u) = −log(1 − u). Therefore taking X = − log(1 − U ) for U ∼ U(0, 1), generates standard exponential random variables. Complementary inversion uses X = − log(U ).
>
> The exponential distribution with rate λ > 0 (and mean θ = 1/λ) has PDF λexp(−λx) for 0  x < ∞. If X has this distribution, then we write X ∼ Exp(1)/λ or equivalently X ∼ θExp(1), depending on whether the problem is more naturally formulated in terms of the rate λ or mean θ. We may generate X by taking X = − log(1 − U )/λ.

coming from [http://statweb.stanford.edu/~owen/mc/Ch-nonunifrng.pdf](http://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Eowen/mc/Ch-nonunifrng.pdf)

Comment: That's the way a distribution is made when you have number like that. I've added further reference there but don't ask me to explain it further as this is far beyond my mathematical expertise :)

Comment: Sadly, not working as expected. The lowest bid seems to be appearing more.

Comment: Just so you know, I'm not a mathematician; so these crazy things mean almost nothing to me, haha. I think I'm looking for an answer by someone who maybe has some experience in doing this type of system and could explain some tricks that they used.

Comment: That the may to do it, figures to prove comes in an edit in 2 minutes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75989/discussion-between-b-enoit-be-and-sysvoid).

Comment: I think it was just being weird. It's now working perfectly. Still don't quite understand it though, but thanks.