# Is there an algorithm for weighted reservoir sampling?

Tags: language-agnostic, sampling

Is there an algorithm for how to perform reservoir sampling when the points in the data stream have associated weights?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The algorithm by Pavlos Efraimidis and Paul Spirakis solves exactly this problem. The original paper with complete proofs is published with the title "Weighted random sampling with a reservoir" in Information Processing Letters 2006, but you can find a simple summary [here](http://utopia.duth.gr/~pefraimi/research/data/2007EncOfAlg.pdf).

The algorithm works as follows. First observe that another way to solve the unweighted reservoir sampling is to assign to each element a random id R between 0 and 1 and incrementally (say with a heap) keep track of the top k ids. Now let's look at weighted version, and let's say the i-th element has weight w_i. Then, we modify the algorithm by choosing the id of the i-th element to be R^(1/w_i) where R is again uniformly distributed in (0,1).

Another article talking about this algorithm is [this one](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/04/hadoop-stratified-randosampling-algorithm/) by the Cloudera folks.

Comment: And a one line python implementation: `heapq.nlargest(k, items, key=lambda item: math.pow(random.random(), 1/weight(item)))`

Comment: Is it possible to do this with replacement?

Comment: @eleanora   There is no point to doing this with replacement since the alias method exist, you need to first create a table, which takes O(n) time, and then each selection is O(1).  Alias however doesn't keep its runtime complexity on selection unless you use it with replacement.

Comment: Cloudera seems to have taken the original article down. What appears to be a copy can be found [here](https://www.geek-share.com/detail/2682415762.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can try the A-ES algorithm from [this paper of S. Efraimidis](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.0256.pdf). It's quite simple to code and very efficient.

Hope this helps,

Benoit