# select random value based on probability chance

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-variables

How do I select a random row from the database based on the probability chance assigned to each row.
*Example:*

```
Make        Chance  Value
ALFA ROMEO  0.0024  20000
AUDI        0.0338  35000
BMW         0.0376  40000
CHEVROLET   0.0087  15000
CITROEN     0.016   15000
........
```

How do I select random make name and its value based on the probability it has to be chosen.

Would a combination of `rand()` and `ORDER BY` work? If so what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Does the chance sum to 1? `SELECT SUM(CHANCE) FROM table`?

Comment: Maybe you find this useful: http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/ and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast

Comment: @lad2025 yes, It sums to 1.0001

Comment: Check [Random Weighted Choice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58457/random-weighted-choice-in-t-sql/454454#454454)

Comment: How many records are there in the table that is having the record selected from it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by using `rand()` and then using a cumulative sum.  Assuming they add up to 100%:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, (@cumep := @cumep + chance) as cumep
      from t cross join
           (select @cumep := 0, @r := rand()) params
     ) t
where @r between cumep - chance and cumep
limit 1;
```

Notes:

- `rand()` is called once in a subquery to initialize a variable.  Multiple calls to `rand()` are not desirable.
- There is a remote chance that the random number will be exactly on the boundary between two values.  The `limit 1` arbitrarily chooses 1.
- This could be made more efficient by stopping the subquery when `cumep > @r`.
- The values do not have to be in any particular order.
- This can be modified to handle chances where the sum is not equal to 1, but that would be another question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirements and was trying to write a query for SQL Sever. My answer is base on @gordon-linoff's query of using cumulative sum for probabilities.

```sql
with rand AS (SELECT id, random=RAND() FROM Tiers)
   , cumsum AS (SELECT id, cum_sum=SUM(probability) Over (Order By id) from Tiers)
Select TOP 1 t.id,
             t.name,
             t.probability
FROM Tiers t
         inner join rand r on t.id = r.id
         inner join cumsum c on t.id = c.id
WHERE c.cum_sum - r.random >= 0
ORDER BY c.cum_sum - r.random ASC
```

I have wrote a full summary to test this at https://github.com/AlahmadiQ8/cumulative-probability-sql

Here is a visual explanation of the cumulative sum probability

| item | probability | cumulative |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| B | 0.3 | 0.5 |
| C | 0.5 | 1 |

If random number `x = 0.45`, then most we should return item `B` because `x` is `0.2 < x <= 0.5`.

```
                           x
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
           0.2               0.5                            1
└──────────┘ └───────────────┘ └───────────────────────────┘
      A              B                        C
```